# How can I unit test a specific DML method?

Tags: simics, dml-lang

I'm writing some common DML code that contains a fairly complex method, something like:

```
saved uint32 checksum_ini;
method calculate_checksum(bytes_t data) -> (uint32 sum) {
    uint32 result = checksum_ini;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size; ++i) {
        result = f(result, data.data[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

My device calls the function indirectly by reading and writing some registers, which makes it cumbersome to unit test all corner cases of the checksum algorithm.

How can I efficiently write a unit test for my checksum implementation?

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to create a dedicated test module, say `test-checksum`, containing a test device, say `test_checksum_dev`, that imports only your common code, and exposes the `calculate_checksum` method to Python, where it is easy to write tests. This is done in two steps: First, expose the method to C:

```
dml 1.4;
device test_checksum_dev;
import "checksum-common.dml";
// Make DML method calculate_checksum available as extern C symbol "calculate_checksum"
// The signature will be:
// uint64 calculate_checksum(conf_object_t *obj, bytes_t data)
export calculate_checksum as "calculate_checksum";
```

The second step is to expose it to Python. Create `checksum.h`:

```c
#ifndef CHECKSUM_H
#define CHECKSUM_H

#include <simics/base/types.h>
#include <simics/pywrap.h>

extern uint32 calculate_checksum(conf_object_t *obj, bytes_t data);

#endif /* CHECKSUM_H */
```

(if you also add `header %{ #include "checksum.h" %}` to the DML file, you will get a hard check that signatures stay consistent).

Now add the header file to `IFACE_FILES` in your module makefile to create a Python wrapping:

```make
SRC_FILES = test-checksum.dml
IFACE_FILES = checksum.h
include $(MODULE_MAKEFILE)
```

You can now call the DML method directly from your test:

```python
SIM_load_module('test-checksum')
from simmod.test_checksum.checksum import calculate_checksum
obj = SIM_create_object('test_checksum_dev', 'dev', checksum_ini=0xdeadbeef)
assert calculate_checksum(obj, b'hello world') == (0xda39ba47).to_bytes(4, 'little')
```