# How to call Python functions from DML?

Tags: simics, dml-lang

I would like to have a DML device with interfaces and register banks as the TOP-level of my device but offload processing to Python. Is there a lightweight method of calling into Python from DML?

This post [How can I unit test a specific DML method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74476435/how-can-i-unit-test-a-specific-dml-method) addresses calling from Python into DML, but I am interested in the reverse.

I think I can create a bunch of custom interfaces to do this, but I'm interested to know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing parts of a device in Python *can* make sense, in particular for code that seldom is invoked (user interaction comes to mind), and when faced with tasks like string manipulation where the shortcomings of a C-like language is particularly painful, or when code sharing with CLI commands is desired.

You can use the `SIM_call_python_function` API to call out to Python from DML. The function uses the equivalent of `eval` on the passed string, so you can find a module-local function by `__import__`:

```
local attr_value_t a = SIM_make_attr_list(0);
local attr_value_t result = SIM_call_python_function(
    "__import__('simics').SIM_version", &a);
log info: "%s", SIM_attr_string(result);
SIM_attr_free(&a);
SIM_attr_free(&result);
```

This API is admittedly not very pretty. Parts of the standard lib for DML 1.2 is in fact written in Python and uses the internal function `VT_call_python_module_function` for this task instead. That API is nicer, but we cannot recommend use of `VT_` functions outside the core Simics team.

Answer (score 2):

This question is really more about the Simics simulator framework than about DML.  Given how Simics works, Python code lives in a separate context.  There is no obvious light-weight way.  Rather, you need to put the Python code in a separate Python class and a separate runtime object and use a Simics simulator interface to orchestrate the calling.

The Python code would in general not be able to access the state of the object anyway, so it would have to be a strict "compute this and return all computed values".  Which is not very convenient for device behavior that is really all about mutating the state of the object.

Even with a bunch of interfaces, there is still the matter of state handling. I guess you need an interface for that as well.